# Super::BeginPlay() , Super::Tick()

Tags: c++, superclass, unreal-engine5

What is the Super:: and why do we use it?

I am new to Unreal Engine. I searched a few and found that we use Super:: with override functions. In this way, we call the base class function. Why do we want to do this? Could someone explain properly, please?

Answer (score 3):

`Super` is a `typedef` for the base class of your current class. It is part of the `GENERATED_BODY()` and will be added by the `UnrealHeaderTool` alongside `ThisClass`.

In the following example, I define a class `UYourClass` that inherits from `UObject`, the base object for a lot of Unreals classes.

```
class UYourClass : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
};
```

The `GENERATED_BODY()` will contain the following code:

```
typedef UYourClass ThisClass;
typedef UObject Super;
```

When you want to call an implementation for an overriden behavior of your base class, you do not need to write the base typename, but instead can just use `Super`. And when accessing the own class, you can also use `ThisClass`. It makes the code a little shorter and more portable, e.g. when you use macros to generate code.

In the following scenario, we inherit from `AActor` and override its `BeginPlay` method, so we can initialize our own object. But because `AActor` also does stuff in its `BeginPlay` implementation (e.g. calling the node "Begin Play" in blueprints), we have to call it as well, otherwise the behavior is faulty.

```
class ABuilding : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
}

void ABuilding::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    // Do your own stuff here
}
```

That's as far as I am willing to describe it. Everything beyond this point is just "C++ works like that" or "OOP works like that" and that's not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Your question is about the basic C++.

**In short**: Super is just the **parent class**.

#### Super Class

The class whose properties are inherited by a subclass is called Base Class or Superclass

#### Sub Class

The class that inherits properties from another class is called a Subclass or Derived Class.

### In Unreal

For example in [Unreal](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UActorComponent/BeginPlay/), when you called the:

```
Super::BeginPlay()
```

It calls the parent class’s BeginPlay() method.

### Parent Class

From the In the Parent class's perspective it's a **virtual** declared method like this:

```
virtual void BeginPlay()
```

That's it.